# Getting a comment attribute from a file in Bash on osx

Tags: macos, bash, xattr

i'm trying to get the comment attribute of a file using xattr in bash on OSX. This is my code I'm running:

```
xattr -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment "/Users/fred/Dropbox/OSXStuff/app.icns"
```

However it is returning hexadecimal instead of the comment string. On the man page for xattr in osx it says that

> if nils are detected in the
>        data, the value is displayed in a hexadecimal representation

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html

What exactly is a "nil" and how did it get in the comment? Is it possible to get the string value of a file comment using xattr in OSX or are there always "nils" in the file comment?

Comment: I think by `nils` they intend "zero bytes" or "null character". If there are such zeroes in the middle of a buffer, it is unlikely for it to be a string, hence it is printed as hexadecimal number

Comment: @Coop, The hexidecimal value includes the comment string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to parse the extended attribute. Ask the metadata system (a.k.a. Spotlight) to directly obtain the information for you:

```
mdls -raw -name kMDItemFinderComment "/Users/fred/Dropbox/OSXStuff/app.icns"
```

The fact that the comment is kept in an extended attribute, let alone the format of that attribute, is an implementation detail that can't be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

Note that mdls (on Yosemite, at least) seems to be able to retrieve/output only the most basic attribute information (not including kMDItemUserTags) if you have specified the item or its containing path in the Privacy tab of the Spotlight Preferences.

As soon as you remove it from the privacy list, and give Spotlight some time to do its thing, the full list of attributes will become available.

Took me a while to figure that out.